# Covert JSON objects inside json objects into a JSON Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hello I have the following JSON structure and I try to make an array of each object inside each object but there is a way to convert it without iterating each element and get every element. 
Or maybe using a Javascript function to get object inside objects and convert to an array?

```
{
  "ES": {
    "130": {
      "code": "A Coruсa",
      "name": "A Coruña"
    },
    "131": {
      "code": "Alava",
      "name": "Alava"
    },
    "...": {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    }
  },
  "CH": {
    "104": {
      "code": "AG",
      "name": "Aargau"
    },
    "...": {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    }
  },
  "...": {
    "...": {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
[
    {
      "code": "A Coruсa",
      "name": "A Coruña"
    },
    {
      "code": "Alava",
      "name": "Alava"
    },
    {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    },
    {
      "code": "AG",
      "name": "Aargau"
    },
    {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    },
    {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    }
]
```

Thanks for your help, I accept any recommendations.

Comment: What do you mean "without using a javascript function"?

Comment: Maybe he means "by magic". But seriously no way to do that without any processing.

Comment: Not possible without some javascript... why don't you want to do that?

Comment: Sorry I try to say without iterating each element and get every element.
Or Using a javascript function that gets each elements on each elements and convert into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iterating over the properties and for assembling the array.

```js
var obj = { "ES": { "130": { "code": "A Coruсa", "name": "A Coruña" }, "131": { "code": "Alava", "name": "Alava" }, }, "CH": { "104": { "code": "AG", "name": "Aargau" } } },
    result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r.concat(Object.keys(obj[k]).map(function (kk) {
            return obj[k][kk];
        }));
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you @Nina Scholz this is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle to convert the data. look at it

https://jsbin.com/suzice/edit?js,output

```
  var data = {
  "ES": {
    "130": {
      "code": "A Coruсa",
      "name": "A Coruña"
    },
    "131": {
      "code": "Alava",
      "name": "Alava"
    },
    "...": {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    }
  },
  "CH": {
    "104": {
      "code": "AG",
      "name": "Aargau"
    },
    "...": {
      "code": "...",
      "name": "..."
    }
  }
};
var list = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){

  Object.keys(data[key]).forEach(function(sub_key){
     list.push(data[key][sub_key]);
  });
  console.log(list);

});
```